# How add wpf usercontrol in xceed wizard control?

Tags: xceed

hi i have tried to use wizard control.
i' d like to call my usercontrol in a page of wizard control.

```
<xctk:Wizard FinishButtonClosesWindow="True">
        <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="IntroPage" 
                               Title="Welcome to my Wizard"
                               Description="This Wizard will walk you though how to do something." />
        <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="Page1" PageType="Interior"
                               Title="Page 1"
                               Description="This is the first page in the process."
                               NextPage="{Binding ElementName=Page2}"
                               PreviousPage="{Binding ElementName=IntroPage}"/>
        <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="Page2" PageType="Interior"
                               Title="Page 2"
                               Description="This is the second page in the process"/>
        <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="LastPage" PageType="Interior"
                               Title="Last Page"
                               Description="This is the last page in the process"
                               CanFinish="True"/>
    </xctk:Wizard>
```

Comment: This does not describe any  problem or actual question

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. It was very simple:

```
myusercontrol my = new myusercontrol();
Page1.Content = my;
```